# Issue in realm relationships: Many-to-One, it creates duplicate objects

Tags: android, realm

Following the official documents guide: [Realm Relationships](https://realm.io/docs/java/0.88.3/#relationships)

I tried to write some code of Many-to-One relationship, and I found some things that are not consistent.

Two POJO `Contace.java` and `Email.java` are defined as follows:

```
public class Email extends RealmObject {
    private String address;
    private boolean active;
    // ... setters and getters left out
}

public class Contact extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
    private Email email;
    // ... setters and getters left out
}
```

**Situation 1:** Create a normal `Email` object and assign to different `Contact` contactA and contactB.

```
Email email = new Email();
email.setAddress("realm_test@gmail.com");
email.setActive(true);

Contact contactA = new Contact();
contactA.setName("Bear");
contactA.setEmail(email);

Contact contactB = new Contact();
contactB.setName("Monkey");
contactB.setEmail(email);

realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealm(contactA);
realm.copyToRealm(contactB);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

After I call `realm.copyToRealm()`, two `Email` objects will be created here. So, when I query `Contact` from Realm, one `Email` object will become two different object? I think this is not a Many-to-One relationship anymore, it just become One-to-One relationship.
[image]

**Situation 2:** Call `realm.createObject()` to create a proxy `Email` object and two proxy `Contact` object, and assign email to contactA and contactB.

```
realm.beginTransaction();
Email email = realm.createObject(Email.class);
email.setAddress("realm_test@gmail.com");
email.setActive(true);

Contact contactA = realm.createObject(Contact.class);
contactA.setName("Bear");
contactA.setEmail(email);

Contact contactB = realm.createObject(Contact.class);
contactB.setName("Monkey");
contactB.setEmail(email);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

[image]
Here we can see just one Email object in the table, and that's what I expected, just as described in the document above.

So, why is there no consistency in **situation1** and **situation2**? Is it a bug in **situation1**? Or am I missing something?

Realm version(s):0.88.3

Android Studio version:2.0

Looking forward to your reply! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for [beeender](https://github.com/beeender)'s answer here: [[issue-2730]](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2730)

> This is the expected behaviour.
>
> In the **situation1**, the email you set to contactA and contactB is a standalone object which is not managed by Realm. So when you copy it to Realm, Realm has no way to know you mean they are the same object. To solve this, you can add a @PrimaryKey to Email and then use copyToRealmOrUpdate. Realm will try to detect if you mean the same email object for both contactA and contactB based on the primary key.
>
> In the **situation2**, since the email object is managed by Realm, when you call setters, Realm knows that email is actually the same one.

Finally I set a `@PrimaryKey` both in `Contact` and `Email`, as following:

```
public class Email extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String address;
    private boolean active;
    // ... setters and getters left out
}

public class Contact extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String name;
    private Email email;
    // ... setters and getters left out
}
```

Then change `copyToRealm()` to `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` on contactA and contactB.

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(contactA);
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(contactB);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

And the relationships betweens `Contact` and `Email` was correctly in **situation 1**.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case two email is created because you are doing `copyToRealm` two times on different instance.

From the docs **Each contact (instance of Contact) have either 0 or 1 email (instance of Email)**

Comment: copyToRealm() call on Contact object, Contact should create 2 times, but I don't think Email should create 2 times, because it's in Many-to-One relationship, not One-to-One relationship, situation2 is what I expected. Or can you explain situation1 with the principle? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should try using copyToRealmOrUpdate() instead of copyToRealm()